# Program for computing Weyl's law

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues

I have calculated the solution to the Laplacian eigenvalue problem on the unit square

$\qquad - \Delta u(x,y) = \lambda u(x,y) \text{ on } {[0,1]}^2$

with the Dirichlet's boundary condition ($u = 0$).

My question is as follows:

Is it possible to write a program which calculate $N(t)$, the number of eigenvalues less than or equal to $t$?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you should not name symbols with capital letters, because the is danger to overwrite a system symbol. In your case `N` is used by the system to coerce a machine  number. So let's call the function `selEV`. As there are an infinity of Eigenvalues, we must restrict the number of Eigenvalues to calculate. You must guess an upper bound of expected eigen values: `maxn`. For an example I choose `maxn=10` :

```
{ℒ, ℬ} = {-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}],
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]};

maxn = 10;
selEV[t_] :=  Select[DEigenvalues[{ℒ, ℬ},  u[x, y], {x, 0, π}, {y, 0, π}, maxn], # <= t &] // Length
```

And e.g. for `t==7`we get:

```
selEV[7]

(* 3 *)
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what the result is selEV[7] = (2, 5, 5). Please help me.

Comment: My second question is do I need to choose the "maxh", because I am giving a $t$ and looking for the number of eigenvalues $\leq t$. Please help me.

Comment: Yes the result for "selEV[7]"  is {2,5,5}.  And yes, you must specify "nmax". As there are infinite many Eigenvalues, it is impossible to calculate all. Instead,  the system calculates "nmax" eigenvalues and returns those that are <= t.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to know what is {2, 5, 5}. Since I am asking for the no. of eigenvalues less than or equal to $t$ for a given number $t$. Please help me.

Comment: 2,5,5 are the eigenvalues <=7, the number is 3. To get the number of eigenvalues you can write: selEV[t:]:= Select[...] //Length. I change my answer accordingly.

Comment: You get zero because all the eigenvalues are larger than 7. The smallest is 19.7

Comment: If you are playing with ",maxn", it may be easier to built it into "selEV":  selEV[t_, maxn_] := 
 Select[DEigenvalues[{\[ScriptCapitalL], \[ScriptCapitalB]}, 
    u[x, y], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}, maxn], # <= t &] // Length   To choose "maxn", first make a guess, calculate the number of eigenvalues with this guess, then increase "maxn" by one and caculate again. If you get the same result you are done. Otherwise increase "maxn" e.g. double it.